# How to POST Blob with Angular 9?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-http

I'm trying to send a blob to my server, but it wont work. I'm using the doctemplater library which creates a Blob. This blob is correct because I'm able to save to local file (with `saveAs(...)`). But now I need to transfer this file to my server too.

```js
let out = doc.getZip().generate({
    type: 'blob',
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
});
```

So I'm trying

```js
const data = {
    name: "test,
    content: out
}

this.http.post<any[]>(this.path, data).pipe(
    catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        // ...
    })
);
```

The problem is that `data['out']` is always empty on server side. So how can I send a blob to the server?

Comment: What do you mean by `data['out']` is empty?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `FormData` like this:

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append(name, value, filename);
```

For more information visit this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append).

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
this.http.post<any[]>(path, data, { responseType: 'blob'})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your service file create a post method

```
updateDistrictLogo(formdata: FormData): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post<any>(
    this.constantService.getUrl(your API URL), formdata,
);
}
```

in your componen.ts file
create a instance of service in constructor

```
   constructor(private ContactService: ContactInformationService) {}
```

then create a method and call api

```
 updatefile() {
  const formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("file", blob);
        this.ContactService.updateDistrictLogo(formdata).subscribe(
            success => {
               console.log(success);
            },
            error => {
           console.log(error);
         }
        );
   }
```